# How do i downgrade a meteor installation on windows?

Tags: node.js, meteor, installation

I tried reading the official manual and two books, but the chage in versions is too large, even the directory sturcture is off.

I tried running meteor bundle --release 1.0.0
no luck

what is the first windows version of meteor, i shold downgrade to?

Answer (score 0):

According to this: http://info.meteor.com/blog/meteor-11-microsoft-windows-mongodb-30 
Meteor supports development on windows as of version 1.1

You have to have at least windows 7 installed. I would recommend that you upgrade your version of meteor to 1.1 or greater by running `npm update meteor`. If you want to use the first version of meteor that supports windows you can run `npm install meteor@1.1`